# What kind of jquery video player should I choose?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, video

I'm looking for a jquery plugin that plays video but most of it is in html5 and it doesn't work on IE. What kind of plugin should I use? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Jquery, it's HTML5, but it has a good fall back for browsers like IE:
[VideoJS](http://videojs.com/)